# Is this a set in New Foundations theory of sets: A={x∈X: x∉f(x)} when X=universal set and f(x)=x?

Tags: set-theory

Does the formula A={x∈X: x∉f(x)} define a set in New Foundations theory of sets (NF) when X=universal set and f(x)=x? If not: WHY?

It can be seen that many elements of universal set (X) satisfy the condition of the formula:

1. If x=∅(it is possible since ∅ is an element of  universal set(∅∈X)):
   Then: f(∅)=∅ and ∅∉∅.
   So, in this case x∈X and x∉f(x), thus ∅∈A. We already have one element of A!
2. If x≠∅:
   This case is also possible, since there is an infinite number of elements of X, for which f(x)=x, but x∉f(x), for example f(x)=x={1,2,3}. But {1,2,3}∉{1,2,3}.

Thus infinite number of elements of A exits, that satisfy condition: x∈X: x∉f(x).

Nonetheless I have to believe, the formula A={x∈X: x∉f(x)} does not define a set in NF, because if it did, [the Cantor’s theorem would be valid in NF](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/544355/flaw-in-the-proof-of-cantors-theorem-does-the-set-of-all-sets-exist). But Cantor's theorem is not valid in NF.
Does this set violate some of the axioms of NF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This set cannot be defined because the formula $x \notin x$ appearing in the putative set definition $\{x \in X : x \notin x\}$ cannot be [stratified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratified_formula#In_set_theory).  The restriction of the separation axiom schema to stratified formulas is how New Foundations manages to avoid Russell's paradox even though it allows a universal set.

To be more precise, I should say that the notation $\{x \in X : x \notin x\}$ cannot be said to define a set solely on the basis of the separation axiom schema of NF.  For certain $X$ the notation $\{x \in X : x \notin x\}$ may happen to define a set; for example if $X$ is the empty set it is safe to say that the notation $\{x \in X : x \notin x\}$ defines a set (also the empty set.)  But if $X$ is the universal set then the notation $\{x \in X : x \notin x\}$ cannot define a set, or the argument of Russell's paradox would lead to a contradiction.

Comment: In fact, you can even find an $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathscr{P}(N)$ and form $\{x\in\mathbb{N}: x\notin f(x)\}$ because there is an indirect way to show that $\iota``\mathbb{N}\simeq\mathbb{N}$. It's only in the very largest sets that this sort of construction seems to fail.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine I'm glad that $\mathbb{N}$ has this property, because I find it very hard to understand its failure intuitively.  I guess NF takes some getting used to.

Comment: It's an odd one. Especially things like its inability to prove $\aleph_n$ exists for all $n$, and nothing like $\aleph_\omega$, unless you assume that $f(x)=\{x\}$ is defined over $\mathbb{N}$--then you get $\aleph$ subscripted with as many $\omega$'s as you like :p

Answer (score 3):

I actually left a comment on this on your other thread. $\{x\in X: x\notin f(x)\}$ does not define a set. The reason is that the defining formula is unstratified: $x$ and $f(x)$ must have the same type to be stratified, but in $x\notin y$, $y$ must be one type higher than $x$. So our axioms don't guarantee such a set and Cantor's paradox disproves such a set.

However, let $\iota``X := \{\{x\}: x\in X\}$ and assume that you have a function $f:\iota``X\to\mathscr{P}(X)$. Then the set $\{x: \neg(\{x\}\subseteq f(\{x\}))\}$ is stratified and does exist for every set, even $V$. If $f$ were a surjection, we could get Cantor's paradox again, so we show that there is no surjection $\iota``X\to\mathscr{P}(X)$. Since there is a surjection $V\to\mathscr{P}(V)$, what this shows is that in NF $\iota``V < V$, which is an odd result central to much of NF's interesting mathematics. It's a lot like if you could divide a tank of goldfish by putting each in their own bowl, but you could do it by using fewer bowls than fish.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now, I understand where I was wrong when I was trying to prove to you that A is not a set. I am happy though that my gut feeling was right - it is not a set in NF. It just took time for me to learn things, that all of the elements of empty set are in any other set, why Trevor Wilson wrote [∅∉∅](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/302064/empty-set-does-not-belong-to-empty-set), and that ∅ is not an element of {1,2,3} but it is a subset of {1,2,3}.

Comment: No worries. Set theory is weird, and set theory with a universal set is weirder. It's why I love NF and ML so much :D